# no tty present and no askpass program specified on remote server

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scripting

When I try to run a script on a remote server using ssh, I am getting "no tty present and no askpass program specified" error.

Main Command line where I am getting error is:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/userdel $user_id
```

Please suggest what need to modify in my command line.

NOTE: I can't modify sudoers file on remote server.

Comment: Thanks Filipe it's worked for me but I am now facing new error.
Usage : userdel [options] LOGIN

Options :
-f , -- force
-h , -- help
-r , -- remove
-R,. -- root CHROOT_DIR
-z, -- selinux-user

Comment: Looks like your script on the remote host is missing an option to the `userdel` command, such as the name of the user to remove... Can you check that? See the script you're running, check how it's selecting the user to be removed and try to figure out why it might be missing... It might be helpful to add a `-x` to your command to print the exact commands executed, as in `ssh $host bash -x /path/to/myscript.sh`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `ssh` the `-t` option, so it allocates a tty (terminal) on the remote side for running your script.

Commands that need to prompt for a password (such as `sudo`) need a terminal, so they can control terminal I/O, such as preventing output of typed characters, so your password doesn't appear while you're typing it.

When you run `ssh $host` (with no command), the SSH client will automatically allocate a terminal (so no `-t` is needed), but if you run it with a command, such as `ssh $host /path/to/script` then it will not allocate a terminal, since for most commands a terminal is not needed and simply redirecting the standard file descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr) is enough... The `-t` option changes that behavior and allocates a terminal even though you're passing it a command line.

See the documentation of the [-t option](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t) in the SSH man page. Look for other references to pty or pseudo-terminal on that page (BTW, they call it pty/pseudo-terminal instead of tty since the terminal is not attached to a real device such as a keyboard/monitor or a serial port... for these purposes, it means about the same.)